# Custom button input type image IE9+

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

I have a problem displaying this button on IE9+. How do I remove the form that appears on the button?

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" name="image" class="file_button_upload" />
```

**CSS**

```
    .file_button_upload{
     width: 160px;
     overflow: hidden;
     font-size: 0px;
     height: 30px;
     margin-bottom: -15px;
     display: inline-block;
     background: url(http://www.festivalbenicomuni.it/wp-content/themes/festival/img/bg_btn.jpg);
     border: 3px solid #000;
     padding: 6px 0px;
     width: 160px;
     font-size: 0px;
     color: #000;
     font-family: 'DINPro-Bold';
     text-align: center;
     overflow: hidden;
     text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/creassociati/v13wfmzu/1/)

Comment: Sound like you need the `<button>` element here. If not, can you provide a bit more details about what you're expecting to happen versus what is happening, with screenshots if possible?

Comment: Why are you using an image for this? Use padding, a background colour and text so that your button can be translated, searched, read by accessibility browsers, etc.

Comment: @Shaggy https://jsfiddle.net/creassociati/v13wfmzu/1/

Comment: @gaynorvader because the input type image does not take the value

Comment: Sorry, I misread your initial post, thought you were using an `image` type `input`. `file` inputs are incredibly difficult to style directly as every browser implements them differently. There are a myriad of solutions & workarounds out there, though.

Comment: yes, but I have not found an answer on how to remove the form that is positioned above the button on IE9

Answer (score 0):

```
You Should use conditional CSS for IE browsers like

<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<style>
 .file_button_upload{
 width: 160px;
 overflow: hidden;
 font-size: 0px;
 height: 30px;
 margin-bottom: -15px;
 display: inline-block;
 background: url(http://www.festivalbenicomuni.it/wp-content/themes/festival/img/bg_btn.jpg);
 border: 3px solid #000;
 padding: 6px 0px;
 width: 160px;
 font-size: 0px;
 color: #000;
 font-family: 'DINPro-Bold';
 text-align: center;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-indent: -9999px;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

OR

You can also use

http://codemug.com/html/css-hacks-for-ie6ie7ie8ie9-and-ie10/